# Formula Inverse Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to learn about matrixes and came across the Inverse Matrix which is calculated using the following steps: [Inverse Marix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V3oF.png)

I understand everything till 2.23 but can't follow how to get from 2.23 to 2.24. I seems to disappear, which should be a 2x2 matrix. Also, how does Aˆ-1 suddenly appears in the equation?

It would be great if you could help me understanding the steps between 2.23 and 2.24.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: RHS in (2.23) has a constant times identity matrix, simply take it to LHS and use the definition of the inverse.

Comment: From 2.22 $I = A(what?)$ Therefore $A^{-1} =$ what?.

Answer (score 0):

$\boldsymbol{A^{-1}}$ has the property $\boldsymbol{AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I}$

Given is the arbitrary  matrix $\boldsymbol{A^{'}}$ which has the property $\boldsymbol{AA^{'}}= \boldsymbol{|A|I}$

Then $\boldsymbol{A^{-1} =\frac{1}{|A|} A^{'} }$

Since $\boldsymbol{AA^{-1} =\frac{1}{|A|}AA^{'} = I}$

Answer (score 0):

Take this as a hint to better understand:

Try with a specific matrix, say
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&2\\3&4\end{array}\right)$$
then its adjoint is
$A'=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
4&-2\\-3&1\end{array}\right)$
so their multiplication will be
$$AA'=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-2&0\\0&-2\end{array}\right)=-2\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$
This is $AA'=-2I$.

Hence
$$A^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{4}{-2}&\frac{-2}{-2}\\\frac{-3}{-2}&\frac{1}{-2}\end{array}\right)$$
which simplifies into
$A^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-2&1\\\frac{3}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right)$.

Finally
the multiplication
$$AA^{-1}=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&2\\3&4\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-2&1\\\frac{3}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right).
$$